RuntimeError: "addmm_impl_cpu_" not implemented for 'Half'
I have been trying to perform a face swap using IP-Adapter, but every time I attempt to generate an image with IP-Adapter enabled, it doesn’t work and results in an error like this :
*** Error completing request
*** Arguments: ('task(phke8go08mg1wvh)', <gradio.routes.Request object at 0x000001B6D1A7F400>, 'photorealistic, woman with a gentle and shy demeanor. She has long, dark indigo hair that reaches down to her waist and is styled with a parting in the middle. (Large and pale lavender eyes:1.2), BREAK, She should be depicted with a calm and serene expression, reflecting her kind nature and inner strength, looking at the viewer', '', [], 1, 1, 2, 760, 512, False, 0.7, 2, 'Latent', 0, 0, 0, 'Use same checkpoint', 'Use same sampler', 'Automatic', '', '', [], 0, 6, 'DPM++ SDE', 'Karras', False, '', 0.8, -1, False, -1, 0, 0, 0, ControlNetUnit(is_ui=True, input_mode=<InputMode.SIMPLE: 'simple'>, batch_images='', output_dir='', loopback=False, enabled=True, module='ip-adapter_face_id_plus', model='ip-adapter-faceid-plus_sd15 [d86a490f]', weight=1.0, image={'image': array([[[153, 108,  75],
***         [153, 108,  75],
***         [153, 108,  75],
***         ...,
***         [104,  73,  52],
***         [104,  73,  53],
***         [103,  72,  52]],
***
***        [[153, 108,  75],
***         [153, 108,  75],
***         [153, 108,  75],
***         ...,
***         [104,  73,  52],
***         [104,  73,  53],
***         [104,  73,  53]],
***
***        [[153, 108,  75],
***         [153, 108,  75],
***         [153, 108,  75],
***         ...,
***         [105,  74,  53],
***         [104,  73,  53],
***         [104,  73,  53]],
***
***        ...,
***
***        [[226, 166, 165],
***         [226, 166, 165],
***         [226, 166, 165],
***         ...,
***         [223, 163, 162],
***         [223, 163, 162],
***         [223, 163, 162]],
***
***        [[226, 166, 165],
***         [226, 166, 165],
***         [226, 166, 165],
***         ...,
***         [224, 164, 163],
***         [224, 164, 163],
***         [224, 164, 163]],
***
***        [[226, 166, 165],
***         [226, 166, 165],
***         [226, 166, 165],
***         ...,
***         [224, 164, 163],
***         [224, 164, 163],
***         [224, 164, 163]]], dtype=uint8), 'mask': array([[[0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         ...,
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0]],
***
***        [[0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         ...,
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0]],
***
***        [[0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         ...,
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0]],
***
***        ...,
***
***        [[0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         ...,
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0]],
***
***        [[0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         ...,
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0]],
***
***        [[0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         ...,
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0],
***         [0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8)}, resize_mode=<ResizeMode.INNER_FIT: 'Crop and Resize'>, low_vram=True, processor_res=512, threshold_a=0.5, threshold_b=0.5, guidance_start=0.0, guidance_end=1.0, pixel_perfect=False, control_mode=<ControlMode.BALANCED: 'Balanced'>, inpaint_crop_input_image=False, hr_option=<HiResFixOption.BOTH: 'Both'>, save_detected_map=True, advanced_weighting=None, effective_region_mask=None, pulid_mode=<PuLIDMode.FIDELITY: 'Fidelity'>, union_control_type=<ControlNetUnionControlType.UNKNOWN: 'Unknown'>, ipadapter_input=None, mask=None, batch_mask_dir=None, animatediff_batch=False, batch_modifiers=[], batch_image_files=[], batch_keyframe_idx=None), ControlNetUnit(is_ui=True, input_mode=<InputMode.SIMPLE: 'simple'>, batch_images='', output_dir='', loopback=False, enabled=False, module='none', model='None', weight=1.0, image=None, resize_mode=<ResizeMode.INNER_FIT: 'Crop and Resize'>, low_vram=False, processor_res=-1, threshold_a=-1.0, threshold_b=-1.0, guidance_start=0.0, guidance_end=1.0, pixel_perfect=False, control_mode=<ControlMode.BALANCED: 'Balanced'>, inpaint_crop_input_image=False, hr_option=<HiResFixOption.BOTH: 'Both'>, save_detected_map=True, advanced_weighting=None, effective_region_mask=None, pulid_mode=<PuLIDMode.FIDELITY: 'Fidelity'>, union_control_type=<ControlNetUnionControlType.UNKNOWN: 'Unknown'>, ipadapter_input=None, mask=None, batch_mask_dir=None, animatediff_batch=False, batch_modifiers=[], batch_image_files=[], batch_keyframe_idx=None), ControlNetUnit(is_ui=True, input_mode=<InputMode.SIMPLE: 'simple'>, batch_images='', output_dir='', loopback=False, enabled=False, module='none', model='None', weight=1.0, image=None, resize_mode=<ResizeMode.INNER_FIT: 'Crop and Resize'>, low_vram=False, processor_res=-1, threshold_a=-1.0, threshold_b=-1.0, guidance_start=0.0, guidance_end=1.0, pixel_perfect=False, control_mode=<ControlMode.BALANCED: 'Balanced'>, inpaint_crop_input_image=False, hr_option=<HiResFixOption.BOTH: 'Both'>, save_detected_map=True, advanced_weighting=None, effective_region_mask=None, pulid_mode=<PuLIDMode.FIDELITY: 'Fidelity'>, union_control_type=<ControlNetUnionControlType.UNKNOWN: 'Unknown'>, ipadapter_input=None, mask=None, batch_mask_dir=None, animatediff_batch=False, batch_modifiers=[], batch_image_files=[], batch_keyframe_idx=None), False, False, 'positive', 'comma', 0, False, False, 'start', '', 1, '', [], 0, '', [], 0, '', [], True, False, False, False, False, False, False, 0, False, None, None, False, None, None, False, None, None, False, 50) {}
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\call_queue.py", line 74, in f
        res = list(func(*args, **kwargs))
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\call_queue.py", line 53, in f
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\call_queue.py", line 37, in f
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\txt2img.py", line 109, in txt2img
        processed = processing.process_images(p)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\processing.py", line 847, in process_images
        res = process_images_inner(p)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\extensions\sd-webui-controlnet\scripts\batch_hijack.py", line 59, in processing_process_images_hijack
        return getattr(processing, '__controlnet_original_process_images_inner')(p, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\processing.py", line 988, in process_images_inner
        samples_ddim = p.sample(conditioning=p.c, unconditional_conditioning=p.uc, seeds=p.seeds, subseeds=p.subseeds, subseed_strength=p.subseed_strength, prompts=p.prompts)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\extensions\sd-webui-controlnet\scripts\hook.py", line 470, in process_sample
        return process.sample_before_CN_hack(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\processing.py", line 1346, in sample
        samples = self.sampler.sample(self, x, conditioning, unconditional_conditioning, image_conditioning=self.txt2img_image_conditioning(x))
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\sd_samplers_kdiffusion.py", line 230, in sample
        samples = self.launch_sampling(steps, lambda: self.func(self.model_wrap_cfg, x, extra_args=self.sampler_extra_args, disable=False, callback=self.callback_state, **extra_params_kwargs))
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\sd_samplers_common.py", line 272, in launch_sampling
        return func()
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\sd_samplers_kdiffusion.py", line 230, in <lambda>
        samples = self.launch_sampling(steps, lambda: self.func(self.model_wrap_cfg, x, extra_args=self.sampler_extra_args, disable=False, callback=self.callback_state, **extra_params_kwargs))
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\repositories\k-diffusion\k_diffusion\sampling.py", line 553, in sample_dpmpp_sde
        denoised = model(x, sigmas[i] * s_in, **extra_args)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
        return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
        return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\sd_samplers_cfg_denoiser.py", line 268, in forward
        x_out[a:b] = self.inner_model(x_in[a:b], sigma_in[a:b], cond=make_condition_dict(c_crossattn, image_cond_in[a:b]))
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
        return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
        return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\repositories\k-diffusion\k_diffusion\external.py", line 112, in forward
        eps = self.get_eps(input * c_in, self.sigma_to_t(sigma), **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\repositories\k-diffusion\k_diffusion\external.py", line 138, in get_eps
        return self.inner_model.apply_model(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\sd_hijack_utils.py", line 22, in <lambda>
        setattr(resolved_obj, func_path[-1], lambda *args, **kwargs: self(*args, **kwargs))
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\sd_hijack_utils.py", line 34, in __call__
        return self.__sub_func(self.__orig_func, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\sd_hijack_unet.py", line 50, in apply_model
        result = orig_func(self, x_noisy.to(devices.dtype_unet), t.to(devices.dtype_unet), cond, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\sd_hijack_utils.py", line 22, in <lambda>
        setattr(resolved_obj, func_path[-1], lambda *args, **kwargs: self(*args, **kwargs))
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\sd_hijack_utils.py", line 36, in __call__
        return self.__orig_func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\repositories\stable-diffusion-stability-ai\ldm\models\diffusion\ddpm.py", line 858, in apply_model
        x_recon = self.model(x_noisy, t, **cond)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
        return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
        return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\repositories\stable-diffusion-stability-ai\ldm\models\diffusion\ddpm.py", line 1335, in forward
        out = self.diffusion_model(x, t, context=cc)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
        return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
        return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\extensions\sd-webui-controlnet\scripts\hook.py", line 905, in forward_webui
        raise e
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\extensions\sd-webui-controlnet\scripts\hook.py", line 902, in forward_webui
        return forward(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\extensions\sd-webui-controlnet\scripts\hook.py", line 809, in forward
        h = module(h, emb, context)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
        return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1568, in _call_impl
        result = forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\repositories\stable-diffusion-stability-ai\ldm\modules\diffusionmodules\openaimodel.py", line 84, in forward
        x = layer(x, context)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
        return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
        return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\sd_hijack_utils.py", line 22, in <lambda>
        setattr(resolved_obj, func_path[-1], lambda *args, **kwargs: self(*args, **kwargs))
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\sd_hijack_utils.py", line 34, in __call__
        return self.__sub_func(self.__orig_func, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\sd_hijack_unet.py", line 96, in spatial_transformer_forward
        x = block(x, context=context[i])
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
        return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
        return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\repositories\stable-diffusion-stability-ai\ldm\modules\attention.py", line 269, in forward
        return checkpoint(self._forward, (x, context), self.parameters(), self.checkpoint)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\repositories\stable-diffusion-stability-ai\ldm\modules\diffusionmodules\util.py", line 123, in checkpoint
        return func(*inputs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\repositories\stable-diffusion-stability-ai\ldm\modules\attention.py", line 273, in _forward
        x = self.attn2(self.norm2(x), context=context) + x
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
        return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
        return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\extensions\sd-webui-controlnet\scripts\ipadapter\plugable_ipadapter.py", line 46, in attn_forward_hacked
        out = out + f(self, x, q)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\extensions\sd-webui-controlnet\scripts\ipadapter\plugable_ipadapter.py", line 294, in forward
        ip_out = self.attn_eval(
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\extensions\sd-webui-controlnet\scripts\ipadapter\plugable_ipadapter.py", line 230, in attn_eval
        return self._attn_eval_ipadapter(
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\extensions\sd-webui-controlnet\scripts\ipadapter\plugable_ipadapter.py", line 252, in _attn_eval_ipadapter
        ip_k = emb_to_k(cond_uncond_image_emb)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\extensions\sd-webui-controlnet\scripts\ipadapter\plugable_ipadapter.py", line 300, in <lambda>
        emb_to_k=lambda emb: self.call_ip(k_key, emb, device=q.device),
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\extensions\sd-webui-controlnet\scripts\ipadapter\plugable_ipadapter.py", line 180, in call_ip
        ip = self.ipadapter.ip_layers.to_kvs[key](feat).to(device)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
        return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
        return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\modules\devices.py", line 169, in forward_wrapper
        result = self.org_forward(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\webui\extensions-builtin\Lora\networks.py", line 584, in network_Linear_forward
        return originals.Linear_forward(self, input)
      File "C:\Users\ignas\Projects\Stable-Diffusion\A1111\system\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 114, in forward
        return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    RuntimeError: "addmm_impl_cpu_" not implemented for 'Half'

---

My IP-Adapter parameters are as follows:

I have also downloaded the IP-Adapter model and saved it here, but it still doesn’t work.

I have also added this argument to the webui-user.bat:
set COMMANDLINE_ARGS=--xformers --lowvram

I am using an NVIDIA GTX 1650 as the GPU.
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 546.26                 Driver Version: 546.26       CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                     TCC/WDDM  | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650      WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   43C    P8               3W /  50W |   3464MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A     34344      C   ...sion\A1111\system\python\python.exe    N/A      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

I have watched many references on how to install ControlNet and IP-Adapter, and I don't think I missed any steps. I have also read discussions about this on various forums but haven't found the answer. Tell me, have I forgotten anything? Oh, and I have installed CUDA and CUDNN according to my GPU.
